# How to connect to HDFS to execute Pyspark and build spark dataframe using DSN?

Tags: python, pyspark, hdfs, dsn

I am accessing an HDFS from my local machine using DSN successfully using the following:

```
    import pyodbc    
    with pyodbc.connect("DSN=CDH_HIVE_PROD", autocommit=True) as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql("""Select * from table1""", conn)
     df
```

However when using ipython on the node we can run code like this to build a spark dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext 
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf    
import pandas as pd
conf = (SparkConf().setAppName('myApp')
        .set('spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead', '2G')
        .set('spark.executor.memory', '18G')
        .set('spark.driver.memory','24G')
        .set('spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled', 'true')
        .set('spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors', '60')
        .set('spark.rpc.message.maxSize', '150'))
sc.stop()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


df = sqlContext.sql("select * from table1")
```

My question is how do I write something similar from my local machine using the DSN connection?

I have installed pyspark to my local machine and can execute the import statements but get error running the code above which is expected to a certain degree since I haven't provided a method of connection:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-c2ccf716ff3e> in <module>
     11         .set('spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors', '60')
     12         .set('spark.rpc.message.maxSize', '150'))
---> 13 sc.stop()
     14 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
     15 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

TypeError: stop() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

If this isn't possible to execute like this, then how else could I use the DSN to build a spark dataframe from HDFS?